# AttributeError: module 'keras_nlp' has no attribute 'models', __verssion, etc

Tags: python, keras, attributeerror, keras-nlp

Hi i have installed keras and keras_nlp but when i try to use any module from keras_nlp it throws AttributeError. For example module keras_nlp has no attribute "models".
i am using python 3.11.0 and the keras version is **3.2.0.dev2024032703**
[image]

when try to write **from keras_nlp.** the VS code suggest me only two options **layers** and **encoders** [image]

please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in Advance <3

i have installed libraries using windows command prompt.

```
pip install keras
pip install keras-nlp
```

and there was no any error while installing these libraries.
and and i have tried this also but same error again.

```
!pip install -q --upgrade keras-nlp
!pip install -q --upgrade keras
```